# Django / Python calculations

Tags: django, django-views, paypal-ipn

I am building a small project that allows a user to get funding for a project.

A project has a field called "amount_raised" that might house an integer such as "123.34"

when a successful payment is done through paypal you receive the `ipn_obj` of which one contains some financial info, i.e. `ipn_obj.mc_gross` which might be "10.23"

how do I perform a calculation in django to get the total value of that?

It's the first time I have dealt with calculations in django so bear with me.

If I try converting them to integers I get an error `invalid literal for int() with base 10`

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number like 123.45 is not an integer. What you need is a [DecimalField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield). Example usage:

> models.DecimalField(..., max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)